# Prove the given inequalities.

Tags: inequality, factorial

> Prove the following inequalities,$$ (n!)^2 ≤ n^n(n)! <(2n)!$$

**My attempt**

I proved one of the inequality using mathematical induction.

***To prove -
  $ (n!)^2 ≤ n^n(n)!$***

For $ n = 1 $,

LHS $≤$ RHS.

Let us assume that for $ n = k$ the inequality is true.

$\therefore$ $(k!)^2 ≤ k^k(k)!$ –––––> [1]

Now let us prove that $ ((k+1)!)^2 ≤ (k+1)^{(k+1)}(k+1)!$ for $ n = k+1$.

Taking LHS,

$=>(k+1)^2(k!)^2 $

$≤(k+1)^2k^k(k)!$     –––––>             [From [1]]

$≤(k+1)(k)^k(k+1)!$

From above we can deduce that,

$LHS≤RHS$.

How to prove the second inequality given in the question?

Answer (score 2):

The left inequality is equivalent to
$$
n! = 1\cdot 2 \ldots n \le n \cdot n \ldots n = n^n.
$$

The right inequality is equivalent to
$$
n^n = n \cdot n \ldots n < (n+1) \cdot (n+2) \ldots 2n = \frac{(2n)!}{n!}.
$$